# Make new predictions with a trained ANN - Keras

Tags: python-3.x, csv, keras

I'm new to the world of ANN and I was wondering, how do I pass a new dataset, possible a new csv, into the model that I alredy trained? I understand, for instance, that:

```
model.predict()
```

only accept arrays, and those arrays have to be of the same shape in order to work. So, how do I pass a complete new csv to generate predictions?

Here is my code, I know that probably it's gonna be a mess, but I'm working on it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Prova_1.csv')
dataset = dataset[np.isfinite(dataset['ID'])]
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:6].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 6].values

# Encoding 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [2])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 1:]

# Splitting
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

#ANN
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the ANN
classifier = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 27, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 55))

# Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 27, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))

# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 1, epochs = 100)

# Prediction
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do all the preprocessing operations to train data for the new data. Because the model trained over your input shape and input features. Make sure your input shape of your input data same as before, unless it will not work.